# how to insert unique value in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

am using mvc,i want to insert a value into the column which is unique. so am checking the column before inserting whether the value exists or not..
Here is the code

```
value=string.Format("{0}{1}", dept.ID, (count + 1));
    if(dept.ID.Contains(value))
            {
                count = count + 1;
                dept.ID = string.Format("{0}{1}", dept.ID, (count + 1));
          }
```

dept is the model in which i have a column named ID..
But the problem is if  data exists in table,am able to get only the next incremented value and not going further...

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Why are you not using auto-increment/identity in database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var count1= count + 1;     
value=string.Format("{0}{1}", dept.ID, count1);
if(dept.ID.Contains(value))
{
    count = count + 1;
    dept.ID = string.Format("{0}{1}", dept.ID, count1);
}
```